# Drupal wait for default submit handler to update database

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I have a custom submit handler, but it has to execute after the default handler updates the database as my custom handler has to retrieve updated data from the db.

How do I tell Drupal to wait for the default handler to finish? I'm also not sure if it executes the custom handler first or the default. But I tried array_shift() to make sure the custom handler executes last. Does it execute handlers synchronously?

In my form alter, I have this code that registers my custom handler:

```
$form['#submit'][]   = 'my_custom_handler';
```

When I submit the form, I want my database to be updated (with the values in the form) before executing my_custom_handler(), as my custom handler has to retrieve data from the database and it has to be the updated one.

Thanks!

Comment: just a suggestion, you can create a menu item and redirect to the menu item after the form submit, In this way you can call my_custom_handler in the new menu item.

Answer (score 0):

`$form['#submit']` is an array of submit handlers and it executes from first to last. And if you just add you submit handler as you mentioned it should execute after default one. You need array_shift() only if you want your handler to execute before default one.

So, from what I see here you are adding handler well. Maybe the problem is somewhere else?